# javamail when reading a message, any reason to use Message instead of MimeMessage, etc?

Tags: jakarta-mail, mime

The javamail faq shows a sample of code on how to read multipart messages.  In general, when reading email, is there any reason not to use the MimeMessage class instead of Message?  In other words, is there any kind of email that using the "mime" version of this class would fail?

Same question for the various other classes, such as MimeMultiart, MimeBodyPart, etc.  Of course I would only cast to MimeMultipart when isMimeType ("multipart/*") returns true, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, JavaMail can support non-MIME email systems, and when JavaMail was first created there were some such systems in wide use.  These days, almost everything has moved to MIME, so there's effectively no reason not to use the MIME versions of the classes.